# Add a string to a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I made an array for a contact list:

```
data = np.array([
    ["Leon","John","Petar"], #Names
    ["Smith","Jones","Taylor"], #Surnames
    ["leon.smith@gmail.com","john.jones@chello.at","peta.tayl@gmail.com"], # EMails
    ["maxefaxe11","Mohrhuhn3000","warpd_fungz"], #Usernames
    ["fakemake11","ichliebehuhn1","lollls123"] #Passwords
])
```

Then I tried coding a registration, that inserts new contacts to the array, to transform the array to this:

```
["Leon","John","Petar","Tom"], 
["Smith","Jones","Taylor","Walker"], 
["leon.smith@gmail.com","john.jones@chello.at","peta.tayl@gmail.com","tom.tow@gmail.com"], 
["maxefaxe11","Mohrhuhn3000","warpd_fungz","tomi12341"], 
["fakemake11","ichliebehuhn1","lollls123","password111"]
```

I tried this code to insert the new contact:

```
def register_contact():
    # Prompt user for details
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    surname = input("Enter surname: ")
    email = input("Enter email: ")
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    password = input("Enter password: ")

    # Add the new contact to the data array
    new_contact = np.array([[name, surname, email, username, password]])
    global data
    data = np.concatenate((data, new_contact), axis=1)

    print("Contact registered successfully.")

register_contact()
# Check the updated data
print(data)
```

But it said:
"ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 5 and the array at index 1 has size 1"

Comment: Well, you are trying to concatenate an array of size 5 along arrays of size 3.

Comment: `data` is (5,3), new contact is (1,5).   It should be (5,1), so the result is (5,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a list of contacts (`[contact1, contact2, contact3, ...]`), you have a list of contact *fields* (`[names, surnames, emails, ...]`). So to add a new contact you must append each field of the new contact to its respective array.

You can do so with [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), turning `new_contact` rows into columns:

```
data = np.concatenate((data, new_contact.transpose()), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`new_contact` shape is `(1, 5)`, you need it to be `(5, 1)`

```
new_contact = np.array([name, surname, email, username, password]).reshape((5, 1))
```